# docker-compose how to run 2 long running jobs

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 infinite process, I am trying to run in the same container. Let's say 2 of the process are one with jupyter notebook and another one is custom python file, workflow.py. Workflow.py has an infinite loop that keeps downloading file at several time. I am trying to run both of them using the following command:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  web_local_postgres_data: {}
  web_local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  notebook:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/worker/Dockerfile
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook
    volumes:
      - ../../:/home/jovyan/work
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    command: nohup python /home/jovyan/work/worflow.py & && nohup start.sh jupyter notebook
```

I tried several command structure but could not achieve what I was looking for. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd typically run only one process in a container, and so to run two processes you'd launch two containers.  In each container run the single command you want to run as a foreground process, overriding the `command:` as necessary.

Since you're already running this in Compose, it's straightforward to add additional containers with basically the same setup:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
x-service-setup: &service-setup
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./compose/local/worker/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ../../:/home/jovyan/work
services:
  notebook:
    <<: *service-setup
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    command: start.sh jupyter notebook
  workflow:
    <<: *service-setup
    command: /home/jovyan/work/workflow.py
```

If you do want to try to force two separate processes into the same container, remember that there must be *some* foreground process, or else the container will immediately exit.  Using a separate container will also let you notice that one process or the other has crashed and restart it; with the single-container setup, you have no way of noticing that that workflow process has exited.

Comment: [This article](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-82-using-yaml-anchors-and-x-properties-in-docker-compose) explains some of the syntax used in this example that may be unfamiliar if you're new to docker-compose.